# Is it possible or right to configure Nginx Ingress Controller on Openshift cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I have Kubernetes cluster setup available on my system. I have verified that my definitions for Ingress controller and Ingress resources working over it as I am able to invoke services inside my K8 cluster from outside the cluster.

Now, I have to move all my resources to Openshift cluster. I just deployed my definitions of Ingress resources from K8 to Openshift but those are not working, as I am not able to access services from outside the cluster. Note that I didn't deploy Ingress controller on Openshift which I did on K8.

The problem is, I don't want to use Openshift Route as an Ingress alternate. So, in order to get my Ingress resource working on OpenShift(OC) cluster what am I supposed to do? Shall I install Ingress controller on Openshift like I did on K8 cluster?

I don't want to use any Openshift specific resource on Openshift cluster, just wanted to utilize embedded Kubernetes of it.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What is your openshift version?

Comment: $oc version
Client version: openshift-clients-4.4.0
Kubernetes version: v1.17.1+3fxxxx

Comment: Looks like not possible with version 4. version 3.11 there is an option https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-ingress-user_managed

Comment: What is not possible? What if I deploy Ingress controller on OC then?

Comment: OpenShift supports `Ingress` objects, the `openshift-ingress` controller should work when you use Ingresses, so what exactly "does not work"? What is the error message you are getting? Are `Routes` being created?

Comment: The ingress resources gets created but it doesn't route the external traffic to target service.